# allowing user to edit a map of a mall using javascript / jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mapping

the scenario is like so- on my website (jQuery on top of asp.net 3.5) I have a static map of a shopping mall (say-
[image]
)
and I want to allow the user to add / remove markers of different types (like 'store', 'restrooms' etc.), each with an associated name. there's no requirement for allowing user to edit the map in any way other than adding / removing these points of interest.
later, a user can search for a specific name or type, and it should be highlighted on the map.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570714/how-to-get-indoor-map-of-a-mall-in-iphone) are mentioned some products such as micello and navteq which seem a little of an overkill to me.
I *think* [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942717/allowing-user-to-edit-add-move-items-in-an-image/943108#943108) is the right direction, but I'd need some more elaboration on that.
any opinion would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is attach a handler to the click event of the image, that will show an input for the name of the marker, and then add the marker to the position of the click once the input is filled in: this will give you an idea (tested http://jsfiddle.net/Rqdv9/)

```
var storage = {}
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img#mallmap").click(function(e) {
storage.posx = e.pageX;
storage.posy = e.pageY;
var nameinput = $("<input />");
nameinput.attr('type','text').appendTo('body');
nameinput.bind('blur',function() {
if ($(this).val() != '')
{
var markertext = $(this).val();
    nameinput.remove();
var marker = $("<div></div>");
marker.attr("class","marker").text(markertext).css('color','white').hide().appendTo('body');
marker.css({'position' : 'absolute','left' : storage.posx, 'top' : storage.posy}).show();
}
}).hide().css({'position' : 'absolute','left' : storage.posx, 'top' : storage.posy}).show();
})
        });
```

This is a very simple, I presume you want to collect more info than just text, so you could have a predesigned dynamic form that is displayed on the click, allowing them to choose an image for the marker etc, and then simply create the element for the marker, and append it as shown.

Comment: And the positions can be saved in a database if you need to re-use them. You can just save the posX and posY to the db, and simply use them again any time you want. You can also save the extra data (img/information/date created etc.).

Comment: I ended up using something similar, along with MobilyMap plugin from @Dheeraj Kumar's answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's a map I love to use - [Mobily Maps](http://playground.mobily.pl/jquery/mobily-map.html)

While it doesn't allow the functionality you're looking for, I'm sure it can be extended pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be really necessary to use a plugin for this?

It seems like it would be pretty easy to just save the position of ones cursor on the map when you click it.

Something like this:

```
$('img').click(function(e) {
    //some div is appearing letting you specify information about the spot
    $.post('/url', {x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY, userData});
});
```

Wouldn't that be easier than load a plugin to do the work for you?